# How to find time complexity when having multiple nested for loops

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I have 3 nested for loops, 1 has two for loops, 2 has five for loops and 3rd has 3 for loops. What will be the time complexity?

Comment: This strongly depends on what is done within these loops. Please provide more details on what is done in the loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

generally, the time complexity depends on the depth of the loops. like `O(n**depth_of_loop)`

in your case, we can assume that first time complexity is `O(n**2)`, second is `O(n**5)`, third is `O(n**3)`. the complexity based on these loops is **`O(n**2) + O(n**5) + O(n**3) => O(n**5)`**

as @philippf said, the real complexity depends on what you do within the loops.